# Map union type to another type

Tags: typescript

I'm just curious know if this is possible in TypeScript. Imagine I've a list on entity identifiers defined as an union type:

```js
type EntityID = 'authors' | 'books' | 'programs';
```

Then, imagine we have the following classes for each of these entities:

```js
class Author { getBirthday() }
class Book {}
class Program {}
```

Is there a way to make this work at type level so that given a concrete `EntityID` TypeScript (and my IDE) know that the return type is a concrete entity class? Something like:

```js
const book = genericGet('books', 10);
book.getBirthday() // This should fail at COMPILE TIME as it's an Author method

const author = genericGet('authors', 23);
author.getBirthday() // This is OK, as author is an Author
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a mapping type from your enum to the types and then use a generic function (a factory method actually) to create the objects.

Something similar to this:

```
type EntityID = 'authors' | 'books' | 'programs';

type MapEntity = {
    'authors': Author,
    'books': Book,
    'programs': Program
}

class Author { 
    getBirthday = ()=>{

    } 
}
class Book {}
class Program {}

function genericGet<T extends keyof MapEntity>(type: T, ...args: any[]): MapEntity[typeof type] {
    switch (type) {
        case "authors":
            return new Author()
        case "books":
            return new Book() as any
        case "programs":
            return new Program() as any
        default:
            throw Error()
    }
}

const book = genericGet('books', 10);
book.getBirthday() // This should fail at COMPILE TIME as it's an Author method

const author = genericGet('authors', 23);
author.getBirthday() // This is OK, as author is an Author
```

A couple of notes:

- You don't need to pass the generic type when using the factory method, as TS will infer it
- You need to specify a `default` clause for the switch even though there are no options there. This is so TS flow analysis is satisfied.
- The type for the variables that call `genericGet` is properly infered

Here is [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=17&ssc=74&pln=17&pc=96#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdsAlqAkgESgXigcgIYCuwAFgPYBOAzjlAD64BGppA1tXbmOaQObl4BbagG4AUKNCQoAWTxh4SUFigBvUVA25CJCtQBcUAIJEy5ADTrNOJq31QAQsxYXNnbn0F2ACu-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) to showcase this:

Comment: That's perfect. I don't mind the internals of the function (thx anyway); I just want to improve the types on a generic wrapper interface; the internal returns `any` and I was returning `unknown` as that's as best as I could do. But with this I can improve a lot the types.